# Kubernetes LoadBalancer type service's external IP is unreachable from pods within the cluster when externalTrafficPolicy is set to Local in GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service, gke-networking

The external IP is perfectly reachable from outside the cluster. It's perfectly reachable from all nodes within the cluster. However, when I try to telnet to the URL from a pod within the cluster that is not on the same node as a pod that is part of the service backend, the connection always times out.

The external IP is reachable by pods that run on the same node as a pod that is part of the service backend.

All pods can perfectly reach the cluster IP of the service.

When I set externalTrafficPolicy to Cluster, the pods are able to reach the external URL regardless of what node they're on.

I am using iptables proxying and kubernetes 1.16

I'm completely at a loss here as to why this is happening. Is someone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: this has nothing to do the `GKE`, its the configuration issue, do you have any kind of network policy setup so far? and I'm assuming you are trying to access the external IP from inside of a pod, which does not work, but from node works, correct me if I misunderstood.?

Comment: Yes. I don’t have any other network policies other than the auto created firewall (created by k8s).

Answer (score 1):

From the official doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/),

> service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy - denotes if this Service desires to route external traffic to node-local or cluster-wide endpoints. There are two available options: Cluster (default) and Local. Cluster obscures the client source IP and may cause a second hop to another node, but should have good overall load-spreading. Local preserves the client source IP and avoids a second hop for LoadBalancer and NodePort type services, but risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading.

The service could be either **node-local** or **cluster-wide** endpoints. When you define the `externalTrafficPolicy` as `Local`, it means node-local. So, other nodes are not able to reach it.

So, you will need to set the `externalTrafficPolicy` as `Cluster` instead.